# How do I apply script to only one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I need help tweaking the following code to apply to only one sheet in the workbook. I want to update column N when any cell in the row is modified starting at row 9. This works perfectly for me except that it tries to update all sheets in the workbook and I just want it to apply to one sheet.

```
function isInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  Logger.log('checking isInRange');

  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > 
checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;
  Logger.log('not outside the rows');

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > 
checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;
  Logger.log('not outside the columns');

  return true;
}

function onEdit(eventObj) {
  var checkRange = thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var checkRange = thisSheet.getRange("A9:N1500");  
  if (isInRange(checkRange, eventObj.range)) {
    Logger.log('cell is in range');
    var propertyCell = eventObj.range;
    var timestampCell = thisSheet.getRange(propertyCell.getRow(), 14);
    timestampCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", 
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
  }  else {
    Logger.log('must be outside the range');
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is a VBA Excel script,you should tag Excel and VBA. Then folks that know those technologies are much more likely to see your question. The question is more about those than timestamp in particular.

Comment: I updated for google sheets. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='WhatEverSheetYouWant') return;
  if(e.range.rowStart > 8 && e.range.rowStart <= 1500 && e.range.columnStart >= 1 && e.range.columnStart < 15) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,14).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you like it. Can you check it off?